# rTorrent/ruTorrent: Bad response from server: (200 [parsererror,getuisettings])

Tags: server, php, rtorrent, rutorrent

I have one Khadas VIM1 Pro that I use with Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 and a rTorrent/ruTorrent installation I took from [this page](https://jes.sc/kb/rTorrent-ruTorrent-Seedbox-Guide.php).

I currently have two 8 TB disks that are almost full, and until about two weeks ago they were working fine.

However, I am not sure what happened, but now I have this error:

```
[07.02.2019 11:20:17] Bad response from server: (200 [parsererror,getuisettings]) {"webui.fls.view":0,"webui.show_cats":1,"webui.show_dets":1,"webui.needmessage":1,"webui.reqtimeout":30000,"webui.confirm_when_deleting":1,"webui.alternate_color":0,"webui.update_interval":3000,"webui.hsplit":0.88,"webui.vsplit":0.54,"webui.effects":0,"webui.fullrows":0,"webui.no_delaying_draw":1,"webui.search":-1,"webui.speedlistdl":"100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,750,1000,1250","webui.speedlistul":"100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,750,1000,1250","webui.ignore_timeouts":0,"webui.retry_on_error":120,"webui.closed_panels":{"ptrackers":false,"prss":false,"pstate":false,"plabel":false,"flabel":false},"webui.timeformat":0,"webui.dateformat":0,"webui.speedintitle":0,"webui.log_autoswitch":1,"webui.show_labelsize":1,"webui.register_magnet":0,"webui.lang":"es","webui.trt.colwidth":[200,100,60,100,100,100,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,80,110,90,200,100,100,100,100,110,80,60,75,75,75,100],"webui.trt.colenabled":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],"webui.trt.colorder":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27],"webui.trt.sindex":2,"webui.trt.rev":1,"webui.trt.sindex2":0,"webui.trt.rev2":0,"webui.fls.colwidth":[200,60,100,100,80],"webui.fls.colenabled":[1,1,1,1,1],"webui.fls.colorder":[0,1,2,3,4],"webui.fls.sindex":-1,"webui.fls.rev":0,"webui.fls.sindex2":0,"webui.fls.rev2":0,"webui.trk.colwidth":[200,60,60,60,60,60,80,85,80,60],"webui.trk.colenabled":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],"webui.trk.colorder":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"webui.trk.sindex":-1,"webui.trk.rev":0,"webui.trk.sindex2":0,"webui.trk.rev2":0,"webui.prs.colwidth":[100,120,60,100,100,100,60,60,60,100],"webui.prs.colenabled":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],"webui.prs.colorder":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"webui.prs.sindex":-1,"webui.prs.rev":0,"webui.prs.sindex2":0,"webui.prs.rev2":0,"webui.plg.colwidth":[150,60,80,80,80,500],"webui.plg.colenabled":[1,1,1,1,1,1],"webui.plg.colorder":[0,1,2,3,4,5],"webui.plg.sindex":-1,"webui.plg.rev%2
```

I have tried to search for a solution, but I don't know where to erase certain files, there is another solution that changes certain PHP stuff, but I don't know where to change it.

Can you help me, please? I don't want to reinstall everything again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove files rTorrent/share/users/USERNAME/settings/uisettings.json and rTorrent/share/settings/uisettings.json.

source: https://github.com/Novik/ruTorrent/issues/974